# Cound not find the class XMPP org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message

Tags: android, xmpp

I downloaded sample code of XMPP project from [Davanum](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/). But when I debug it, it gives me a log error "cound not find the class XMPP org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message", even though I have added all smack jars.

I get exception at this line.

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
            new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
```

and exception is `InvocationTargetException.<init>(Throwable) line: 50`

Please help me,
Thanks!

Comment: This means that your class library is not properly imported.  Make sure the .jar is included in your build path

Comment: all the jars have been included

Comment: They might be included in the project, but are they included in the build path?

Comment: no dude i have added them to build path as well

Comment: is there any other suggestion???

Comment: You might find tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958882/why-am-i-getting-an-invocationtargetexception-android-2d-game).  You're likely passing in a null to the XMPPConnection constructor, and it's getting wrapped, because the .jar is an outside component.  Your host or service is probably null, but I can't see where they are instantiated :)

Comment: [I suggest using a newer version of aSmack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)