# Set Text for pop up

Tags: android

I have a button with the onClick name of `checkResult`.

```
public void checkResult(View view){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout myRoot = new LinearLayout(this);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_result_popup, myRoot);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //what I want to show in the popup
    TextView scorePopup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_popup);
    scorePopup.setText("Your score: " + score);

    Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }});

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(checkResultButton, 100, -1200);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.update();
}
```

When `checkResult` button is clicked, `layout_result_popup` is displayed.

I directly put a button at main activity and use onClick to show popup. So far, I managed to show the popup text in XML. But when I try to set some text to it, my app crashed.

Help please. :)

Comment: And what is in the logcat?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Here's what it says:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: well, something, somewhere is null ... and you are trying to call `null.whatever(..)` or get `null.whatever`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is checkResultButton?

Comment: checkResultButton is the button that when clicked, will show the popup. I've actually changed the name of some views / buttons here so that it seems less confusing to some people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace those 2 lines with this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView countView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.count);
                countView .setText("Count: " + count+ "/" + totalCount);
            }
        });
```

It very likely even works with the first line outside of the `runOnUiThread`

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. :( Logcat: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Check this out, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958882/why-am-i-getting-an-invocationtargetexception-android-2d-game

Comment: @RyanPhill You are likely trying to operate on something that is `null` in your code.

Comment: @RyanPhill What is the second parameter of `inflate()` supposed to be? You put `null` for it

Comment: @RyanPhill I just checked the developer site for LayoutInflator and the second parameter is a `ViewGroup` for every type. That must be where you are getting the exception. You need to put something there.

Comment: Hi Benyam sorry for the late reply. I actually followed an online tutorial, that's why the second parameter of `inflate()` is `null`, since I did not change anything from the original code. Does this mean that the `null` is where I should make some changes at?

Comment: Well according to the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) you need to pass in a ViewGroup into the second parameter...passing in null would probably be the reason you are crashing. The ViewGroup would be a root view that is an "Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy". Otherwise I can't immediately see why the app is crashing. Try that and if it doesn't work tell me.

Comment: So let's say MainActivity.java is the parent that holds this popup. A button called `popup` will show the popup. So this button is the one that I should insert into the parameter?

Comment: @RyanPhill Well...ViewGroup is the parent of the pop-up you would put in. It wouldn't be a button since that isn't a viewgroup. Read this ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). Whatever view the pop up is generating from is the parent view

Comment: @RyanPhill Also post your log where the error occurs. So I can see the errors and execptions you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful all the way, Benyam. I still couldn't get it working. Not sure why. I have edited my question, so that you can see my actual code. Please have a look.

Comment: @RyanPhill Post the log of the error you get in the question so we can know exactly what lines are causeing the crash and what the errors are. Another thing I see is one thing you should do is declare your varibales within the button outside instead. The button shouldn't be where a `TextView` is identified. The code within a button should just tell those things what to do.

Comment: This is what I got from logcat: `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. Sorry that I forgot to include this. The reason why I didn't declare my text view outside is because at `onCreate`, the xml layout is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);`, but the popup xml is `R.layout.layout_result_popup`.

Comment: Edit your question with the whole log

Comment: What are the _exact_ line(s) throwing the exception, a `InvocationTargetException` wraps an exception so it is likely a `NullPointerException` being wrapped, edit the question with the whole logcat. It tells you what line is causing it so locate the line and edit the question to show it

Comment: @RyanPhill It doesn't matter what you set the content view as...you can declare all those view variables in onCreate...you aren't setting the content view to the pop-up's XML

Comment: Hi Benyam sorry for the late reply. I was abroad for the past week. Would you mind if we discuss about this via email? My email address is ryanphill02@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks a lot Benyam. Everything works fine now. So glad to have had your help!